# How to ignore a feature while including it as part of feature set in Weka GUI

Tags: weka

I am using Weka GUI to run a NaiveBayes classifier on an online post. I am trying to track the instances (online posts) that are incorrectly predicted so that I can learn further how I can improve the features.

Currently, I have a work around to do that: I generate the data with unique ID included, and when I import to Weka I remove the uniqueID. I then attach the prediction appender, which saves prediction results to an .arff file. I read through the file to find instances with bad performance. For incorrectly classified instances, I use certain feature values that give unique enough value for each instance and find the instance with the same value from my original data, which contains the unique ID. As you can see, this is a truly time consuming process.

I would love to hear if there is a way to ignore a feature, which in my case is the unique ID of an instance, while keeping it as part of the data when running the classifier.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if weka GUI has a direct option for that. However you can achieve the same through commandline

```
java weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -F weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.RemoveType -W weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -t G:\pub-resampled-0.5.arff -T G:\test.csv.arff -p 1 -distribution > G:\out.txt
```

In the above example, first attribute is an an identifier (string). RemoveType filter will remove all string fields while building the model. However, you can still ask weka to include that identifier as part of the output (predictions) by passing as argument to **-p**. In my case first attribute (partner_id) is identifier so it gets listed in the output along with predictions. (-distribution option is to output prediction scores for all class labels). You can get more details from http://weka.wikispaces.com/Instance+ID

```
=== Predictions on test data ===

 inst#     actual  predicted error distribution (partner_id)
     1        1:?        2:0       0,*1 (8i7t3)
     2        1:?        2:0       0,*1 (8i7u1)
     3        1:?        2:0       0,*1 (8i7um)
     4        1:?        2:0       0.1,*0.9 (8i7ux)
     5        1:?        2:0       0,*1 (8i7va)
     6        1:?        2:0       0,*1 (8i7vb)
     7        1:?        2:0       0,*1 (8i7vf)
```

Hope you find this helpful..

Comment: Thank you! It's really helpful to know that I can output an attribute. So in fact my identifier is numeric, so I ran removeType on numeric. And my identifier was just gone, and it didn't come back when I tried to output the attribute. Is it because it's numeric? String attributes don't go away?

Comment: @JinaHuh did you indicate that one of the attributes has to be included as part of the prediction scores? Why don't u label that identifier as string in your arff file and try?

Comment: How do you label an identifier as string in arff?

Comment: Specify the attribute as String.. "@attribute partner_id string"

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming to this question late, it **is** possible to do it in the GUI. Here is the answer I got from Mark Hall (from the Weka project):

> The FilteredClassifier is available in the GUI or command line just
>   like any other classifier. Just configure it with your base classifier
>   and a Remove filter (to remove the ID etc. before the training/test
>   data is passed to the base classifier).

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on Nicholas' answer: if you want to do it from the GUI, in addition to selecting the FilteredClassifier, you should open "More options..." in the "Test options" box and enter the index of the identifier attribute into the "Output additional attributes" field. To enable this field, you have to tick the "Output predictions" box first.

In Weka 3.7, the additional attributes must be specified as a parameter of the chosen method for "Output predictions" by left-clicking on the field (e.g. PlainText).